# Create a VPN client in C#

Tags: c#, networking, vpn

I have been looking at different VPNs, and it seems like they don't have great encryption (like the default Windows XP VPN server).

I wanted to see if I could create my own, using C#. But I don't know how to create a client that will intercept all of the packets, and forward them to a VPN server.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net).

Comment: ha hah...nvm my answer! good choice.

Comment: Let's all face it. We're not as smart as the people that KNOW encryption are. Why re-write what works?